# T4 equivalent for node.js

Tags: node.js, template-engine, t4

I'm a node.js newbie. I need to produce dynamic js output at runtime, from static snippets and from data cooked by the server, with control blocks using server data. In  DOT NET I used T4 to achieve this, but it seems to me as if all node.js template engines only know how to produce HTML. Is there any T4 equivalent for node.js, e.g. one that can output plain text that is not HTML and uses server control blocks?

Comment: A templating engine is not bound to one type of file. A quick search gave me [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) (variable replacements only) and [nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) (logic blocks, inheritance and some other cool stuff).

Comment: @ShanShan, I think your comment is not entirely correct, look for example at node-blade, and all haml.js based modules like jade and haml-coffee. They explicitly know how to parse html directives for html generation. Haven't tested yet, but from looking at code examples looks like nunjucks, swig, and maybe ejs or handlebars could fulfill  my requirement.

Comment: I don't understand why my question has been put on hold. I am not asking for opinions over which module is bigger and better. I'm actually asking which module has facilities suitable for for fulfilling my requirements in the first place, because it looks like most do not.

Comment: Based on the back-and-forth in the answers, it looks like it's not really clear what you're asking. If you edit your question and add more detail, the question will go back in a moderation queue to be potentially reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Most templating engines can produce Javascript as readily as they produce HTML. In most cases, though, it is better to not dynamically produce Javascript. Instead, use static Javascript controlled by dynamically generated data, such as a JSON object embedded in your rendered html.

This has a few advantages:

- Safety. You're less likely to accidentally produce invalid javascript or, worse, incorrectly embed user-generated content into your script in a manner that opens you to XSS attacks.
- Speed. You want to keep your static and dynamic content separate. The static content can be a single compiled bundle of Javascript hosted on a separate domain optimized for serving static content, and the dynamic content can be a relatively small file produced by your node.js server.

Comment: Please see my comment to iblancasa's answer. I have no rendered HTML and I have no control or knowledge over what happens on the client, as I am providing a 3rd party component.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do the same in NodeJS (I think no).

You can work using the server and the client:
you can return a static template to the client and the data separately and join it in the client. Then, when you need to change something in the view (any kind of data) you can generate again it using the dinamic data and the static template (or simply use any library like jQuery to edit DOM).

You can do it with client template engines like Moustache.js .

I hope my answer will be helpful you!

Comment: I guess my description was not explicit enough. My dynamic js output is a 3rd party component that is not bound to any markup. It is served to and cached on CDN servers, cooked and sealed. The client receives an end-product, so there is no room for moustachoids.

Comment: So you need to write an offline program that accepts some input and produces a Javascript file? A templating language such as mustache.js is still the correct solution. You will use it purely for convenient string rendering in your program; the fact that you happen to be generating a Javascript file is immaterial.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Powershell it isn't specific to .net so you could use it for nodejs ? see  https://danielbrannstrom.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/powershell-as-a-t4-text-template-alternative/